# Data sorting, combining 2 lines

Tags: python, text-files

I have a file looking this way:

```
    ;1;108/1;4, 109
    ;1;51;4, 5
    ;2;109/2;4, 5
    ;2;108/2;4, 109
    ;3;108/2;4, 109
    ;3;51;4, 5
    ;4;109/2;4, 5
    ;4;51;4, 5
    ;5;109/2;4, 5
    ;5;40/6;5, 6, 7
```

where

```
    ;id1;id2;position_on_shelf_id2
    ;id1;id3;position_on_shelf_id3
```

as a result, i want to get:
        id1;id2-id3;x
where x are common shelf positions for both id2 and id3, it should look like this

```
    1;108/1-51;4
    2;109/2-108/2;4
    3;108/2-51;4
    4;109/2-51;4, 5
    5;109/2-40/6;5
```

my script works fine up to the moment where I need to type common shelf positions. I tried using .intersection, but it is not working properly, when I have positions consisting of double characters (pos:144-result: 14; pos:551, result: 51; pos:2222-result: 2 i.e)

```
result = id2_chars.intersection(id3_chars)
```

any fix for intersection? or maybe some better method on your mind?

code so far:

part1 - merge every 2nd line together

```
exp = open('output.txt', 'w')
with open("dane.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    strng = ""
    for i in range(1,len(content)+1):
        strng += content[i-1].strip()
        if i % 2 == 0:
            exp.writelines(strng + '\n')
            strng = ""

exp.close()
```

part2 - intersection:
exp = open('output2.txt', 'w')

```
imp = open('output.txt')
for line in imp:
    none, lp1, dz1, poz1, lp2, dz2, poz2 = line.split(';')
    s1 = poz1.lower()
    s2 = poz2.lower()
    s1_chars = set(s1)
    s2_chars = set(s2)
    result = s1_chars.intersection(s2_chars)
    result = str(result)
   exp.writelines(lp1 + ';' + dz1 + '-' + dz2 + ';' + result + '\n')
exp.close()
```

** i did not filtered the result for my needs yet (it is in "list" form), but it won't be a problem once I get the right intersection result

Comment: Please include the code you have so far.

Comment: code added (some letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you try to intersect 2 sets of characters while you should intersect positions. So you should at least use:

```
...
s1 = poz1.lower()
s2 = poz2.lower()
s1_poz= set(x.strip() for x in s1.split(','))
s2_poz = set(x.strip() for x in s1.split(','))
result = s1_poz.intersection(s2_poz)
result = ', '.join(result)
...
```

But in fact, you could easily do the whole processing in one single pass:

```
exp = open('output.txt', 'w')
with open("dane.txt") as f:
    old = None
    for line in f:               # one line at a time is enough
        line = line.strip()
        if old is None:          # first line of a block, just store it
            old = line
        else:                    # second line of a bock, process both
            none, lp1, dz1, poz1 = old.split(';')
            none, lp2, dz2, poz2 = line.split(';')
            poz1x = set(x.strip() for x in poz1.tolower().split(','))
            poz2x = set(x.strip() for x in poz2.tolower().split(','))
            result = ', '.join(poz1x.intersection(poz2x))
            exp.write(lp1 + ';' + dz1 + '-' + dz2 + ';' + result + '\n')
            old = None
```

Comment: thank you, I found similar solution on my own later yesterday